# EnumWindows and CloseHandle

Tags: c, windows, winapi

Do I need to call [`CloseHandle()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211.aspx) on handles returned by [`EnumWindows()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx)?

Comment: I would like answers to be supported by evidence, random guesses aren't good enough for me. E.g. does closing or not closing a window handle affect any resource release?

Comment: `CloseHandle` works on `HANDLE` types.  Window handles are of type `HWND`.  That should already be a strong hint that you shouldn't be using one with the other.

Comment: @jamesdlin: that's not prominently visible - `HANDLE` has many aliases.

Comment: Can you give us some of these well known aliases?

Comment: `grep 'typedef HANDLE ' *` in my `include` folder finds 22 lines. `HHOOK`, `HGLOBAL`, `HLOCAL`, `HPOWERNOTIFY` to name a few.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Except that you release `HHOOK` via `UnhookWindowsHookEx`, `HGLOBAL` via `GlobalFree`, `HLOCAL` via `LocalFree`, and `HPOWERNOTIFY` via `UnregisterPowerSettingNotification`.  Sure, those types happen to be `typedef`ed to `HANDLE` under the hood, but treating them as such would be an abstraction violation.

Comment: The CloseHandle documentation clearly lists the handles it can close.

Comment: No need for random guesses. All you have to do is read the msdn topic that you linked to for CloseHandle.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx  "The CloseHandle function closes handles to the following objects:" and "Windows" is not among them.

Comment: And thank you for your question.  It good to land on this question from Google, I was facing same query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You only ever use CloseHandle() on handles returned by functions in kernel32.  They are reference counted, closing the last handle destroys the object.  File, mutexes, events, that sort of object.

Window handles are different, their lifetime is determined by the user.  Or an explicit DestroyWindow() call in a program.  You don't want to call DestroyWindow() when you enumerate windows.

GDI handles are different yet, they often have dedicated release functions.  CreatePen vs DeleteObject, GetDC vs ReleaseDC, CreateDC vs DeleteDC, etc.  In case of doubt, always consult the corresponding creation function to see how it needs to be released again.  The SDK documentation never skips that.  This is otherwise documented by omission, the EnumWindows documentation doesn't say that you need to release the handle so you don't.

So no.

Answer (score 0):

I would say no. That is for destroying things that you no longer need. You didn't call `CreateWindow`.